# @font-face rule not working in codepen

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am recreating on a email sign up page for my coding course. Here is the example of what I am suppose to recreate:
[image: Email Sign Up Page model]

In order to make this project look at closely as possible to the example, I have been trying to use the @font-face rule with the Wisdom font to get the headlines with  tags to have the wisdom font. My course suggests using Mozilla Developer Docs to get Wisdom Font to work. I have been using the [Mozilla Developer Docs @font-face page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) to help me and my coding course provided the Wisdom font in zip files. I downloaded the file and extracted all the contents. Once I downloaded the file, I followed the syntax in Mozilla Docs. However the font changed from Comic Sans to Arial. I downloaded the Wisdom font file again and played around with the syntax and changing the src url to see if that would help. However the font still remains on Arial. I emailed my teacher about the issue and she sent me another link. [My teacher's link](http://theme.fm/2011/07/how-to-use-web-fonts-and-the-font-face-css-method-1081/) has the @font-face kit generator and I used that to get the file formats on my computer. After I used the kit, I followed the example syntax for both basic and cross compatibility. However the font still remains the same.

Right now my code for the @font-face on my site looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fonts/WisdomScriptAIRegular';
src: url('fonts/ wisdom_script-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/ wisdom_script-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/ wisdom_script-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/ wisdom_script-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/ wisdom_script-webfont.svg#WisdomScriptAIRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is my [email sign up code so far](http://codepen.io/BritishPandaChick/pen/ZWGvyj) which shows what it looks like. Am I using the wrong src url for my code? Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue #1: You shouldn't have any spaces in your URLs.

```
src: url('fonts/wisdom_script-webfont.eot');
```

Issue #2: Much like an `img src`, your web font URL must point to a real resource hosted online somewhere. Right now, it's pointed to a `fonts` folder, which I'm guessing doesn't exist on the CodePen domain. If you have a CodePen Pro account, you can upload the font files via the **Assets** area (https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/asset-hosting/); otherwise, you'll need to put the font files online somewhere else and point to that URL.

Issue #3: Your `font-family` should reference the name of the font without the folder/URL, eg:

```
 font-family: 'WisdomScriptAIRegular';
```

This is the same name you should use later in your CSS to use the font, too, eg:

```
.recent_posts{
   font-family: 'WisdomScriptAIRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the font files online so I can have CodePen access them? I did fix the spaces in the URLs.

Comment: Hi, Sarah. If you have a CodePen Pro account, the asset upload link should be here:  http://i.imgur.com/lJ6YRzX.jpg
Otherwise, you have to host them yourself on a web server.

Comment: Another option would be to use a similar Google Web Font:  https://www.google.com/fonts#ReviewPlace:refine/Collection:Pacifico|Satisfy|Cookie|Rochester|Grand+Hotel|Leckerli+One|Norican|Sofia

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I was using the src twice. Thanks for your help!